# Condition to on $k$ to make the two sequences "disjoint"?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have two sequences $a_n = n + \frac12 $ and $ b_m = k ( m + \frac12) $ for some constant $k>0$, and $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$

I am trying to find $k$ such that $a_n$ and $b_n$ have an empty intersection if they are viewed as sets. I think it should be that $k$ cannot be odd and if it is any other real number that would work.

For some really strange reason, I am struggling to prove this. Clearly, if we assume there is some $n$ and $m$ for which $a_n = b_m$, then $k$ must be rational, but I can't seem to go from there. I also tried to argue that $b_m - \frac12 $ must be an integer, but again I got stuck.

Appreciate any help massively, thank you!

Comment: did you mean $b_m = k(m+\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: What domain set is $k$ drawn from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as some users have noted it should be $b_m=k(m+\frac 12)$.

If $a_n=b_m$ for some $n,m\in \mathbb N$ ,then $k$ must be positive. If you take $k$ as any even positive integer, say $2p$ then $a_n\notin \mathbb N$  but $b_m=2pm+p\in \mathbb N\,\,\forall n,m\in \mathbb N$. Thus you are done. If $k$ is any odd positive integer, say $2p+1$ then $b_m=p(2m+1)+m+\frac 12=a_n$  for
$n=p(2m+1)+m$ .

In general if $k\notin \{{2n+1\over 2m+1}:n,m\in \mathbb N\}$, then $a_n\neq b_m\,\,\forall n,m\in \mathbb N$ .

Answer (score 1):

$a_n \not= b_m => (n+\frac{1}{2}) \not= k (m+\frac{1}{2}) => 2n+1 \not= k(2m+1)$

Which means that $ k \not= \frac{2n+1}{2m+1}$ and so for instances $k\not=1,\frac{3}{5} ,3,\cdots$